# Simple(st) BI use case for confidence/prediction ellipse visual

Tags: data-visualization, inference, intuition

I noticed confidence ellipse visuals are not uncommon in scholarly journals, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0scA5J9sfVIC&pg=PA385&lpg=PA385&dq=confidence+ellipse&source=bl&ots=6eQVBvn4_a&sig=ACfU3U0FH1EQE30Bfkcp90XbvZlvhoQySA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj53PXN6O3kAhUtL6YKHUM_AmoQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) is one concerning equity premiums. Here is the kind of confidence ellipse that I'm considering for visual reference:

[image]

Usually when looking at the off-the-shelf business intelligence dashboards, it's pie charts, bar charts and maps that are the most common. I suppose there are a few reasons, ranging from ease of computation to axiomatic interpretation. Initially, these findings compelled me to believe that ellipse scatter plot visuals were only for the academic elite.

Lately though I'm beginning to reconsider. Maybe I have not given the visual it's due credit (whether from lack of time/applications). Perhaps someone can do a better job in pitching it for BI than me.

### Question

How would a statistician pitch the merits of this visual to the "decider" of the business?

**Edit:**

After reading up on prediction ellipses from comments: "If you overlay a prediction ellipse on your sample and the sample does not "fill" the ellipse in the way that bivariate normal data would, then you have a graphical indication that the data are not bivariate normal." -- Why would a BI end user care if two variables are bivariate normal or not?

**Further Clarifications:**

- **Data:** Let's start with the classic price / returns. Data engineering/manipulation/transformations are allowed. However assume the business does not have some fancy in-house model at their disposal.
- **Audience Statistical Literacy:** Basic-Intermediate (a few footnotes should suffice for them to understand, feel free to weigh-in on footnote content)
- **Note:** If finance isn't your thing, I don't mind, you may assume any two-variable data set in an industry you are familiar with to build your case.

Comment: If this is truly a confidence region, it must correspond to a huge level of confidence!  Are you sure it's not intended to be a tolerance region or prediction region?

Comment: @whuber you may have hit the nail on the head, I didn't know about tolerance or prediction regions

Comment: If you would like to modify your question, please feel free to edit the post.

Comment: +1: you hit it on the head with "Why would a BI end user care if two variables are bivariate normal or not?"  Indeed, most statisticians wouldn't care either.  There are more fundamental issues involved.  They concern establishing a reference distribution based on the first two (bivariate) moments of the data with respect to which one can learn a great deal (and succinctly describe) the "shape" of the data; normality rarely is of any interest.

Comment: @whuber It seems we have a consensus that normality is merely descriptive and not analytical enough for BI, but would you mind elaborating more about other options (tolerance or otherwise), perhaps, as an answer? I'm quite interested